# How to access the parent tab's url from a popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I have a default_popup:popup.html defined in the manifest.json, from which I want to access the current tab that initiated the action. The tabId and the tab url are required. How do I go about doing it ?

Comment: Perhaps this might help you: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-getCurrent. It returns the currently selected tab when you execute it (i.e. tab that initiated the action when you run it when the popup opens), and returns an object that contains the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the correct page. I am now doing `chrome.tabs.getSelected(undefined, function (tab) { 
    // use tab.url, tab.id
}` to get it.

Comment: Does that work? According to the documentation, you should just pass the callback and no `undefined`.

Comment: the integer windowId is optional, but without putting an argument there the js compiler throws an error. `undefined` seems to handle it correctly, @pimvdb

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help you:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-getCurrent.

It returns the currently selected tab when you execute it (i.e. tab that initiated the action if you run it when the popup opens), and returns an object that contains the data you need.

Comment: at least as of 2023 (maybe the docs changed) this does not work. "Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. Returns undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example, a background page or popup view)." NOTE: the "if called from a non-tab context"

Comment: getCurrent always worked like this, so this answer was always incorrect.