# How to get the parent window of a extension popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When a user has multiple browser windows open, and they click on my extension icon in one of these windows i want to know the window id of the window the user is clicking in.

Only question I could find on this is [How to access the parent tab's url from a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023311/how-to-access-the-parent-tabs-url-from-a-popup) which I have now commented on. Maybe things were different with that API in 2011 but is specifically says it does not work now.

I am testing this by having my popup js send a message back to the background.js. This is a MV3 extension.

In this context `chrome.windows.getCurrent()` returns the last window created. It also appears that the popup itself is not a window. However `chrome.windows.getLastFocused()` seems to give me the right window.

Am I to rely on getLastFocused or is there another way to do this?

Comment: chrome.tabs.getCurrent was always the wrong answer. You can use chrome.windows.getLastFocused but make sure to do it right away, as later the user may focus a different window.

Comment: yeah who would thought it a good idea to make "getCurrent" be the last created. Oh thats right the Google chrome extension team.

Answer (score 1):

Filter windowTypes

```
chrome.windows.getLastFocused({ windowTypes: ["normal"] })
```

Check doc for more detail:
[method-getLastFocused](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-getLastFocused)

Comment: why the filter? As I am clicking to open the popup and the default is normal popup why do you think I need it?